# System.Threading.Timer issue (only timer in mvvmcross)

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, timeout, mvvmcross

The Task was to create a simple WebRequest service with maximal Timeout. So if the loading (getting response) is longer than for example 5 sec, than the error is returned.

According to mvvmcross examples I have create IService

```
public interface IWebRequestService
{
    void GetHtmlFromUrl(Action<string> success, Action<Exception> error  , string url );
}
```

then Service

```
public class WebRequestService : IWebRequestService
{
    public void GetHtmlFromUrl(Action<string> success, Action<Exception> error, string url)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        var tw = new TimeOut(500);
        tw.TimeHasElapsed += sender => { if (!request.HaveResponse) request.Abort(); };


        try
        {
            request.BeginGetResponse(result => ProcessResponse(success, error, request, result), null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            error(exception);
        }
    }

    private void ProcessResponse(Action<string> success, Action<Exception> error, HttpWebRequest request,
        IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                success(text);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            error(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

And TimeOut class

```
public class TimeOut
{
    public delegate void EventHandler(object sender);

    private readonly int _time;
    private Timer InnerTimer;

    public TimeOut(int time)
    {
        _time = time;
        InitializeTimer();
    }

    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        InnerTimer = null;
        InnerTimer = new Timer(Callback, null, _time, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void Callback(object state)
    {

        InnerTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        if (TimeHasElapsed != null) TimeHasElapsed(this);
    }

    public event EventHandler TimeHasElapsed;
}
```

When I am getting response for a first time, everything works OK. But for the second and next times there is problem with Timer. The Callback method is called x times and it causes lags in UI.

It is even called in some sequence (2^n), where n is attempt to get response.

I have tried to put Timer.Dispose(); Timer = null; if(timer != null) into Callback method.
Nothing has changed.

Does exist solution for this?

Edit:
Actually this code is totally ok, problem was that I have forget about null one event in ViewModel.

Comment: I can't see any n^2 issue from reading through your code. The only issue I can spot in your code is that maybe the timer could be garbage collected before it times out - but that would cause less calls not more. Perhaps you could add some trace to the start of all of `GetHtmlFromUrl`, `ProcessResponse` and `Callback` - if you add some example trace to this question then this would illustrate the pattern for all readers. Also including which platform(s) you are executing on might help.

Comment: Actually the problem was somewhere else. Sorry, I should have tested also GetFromUrl method (it was also launched x times).